# Django Heroku static files in production

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I've read several related posts to collecting static files in production, but still can't seem to figure out why collectstatic fails. Why would the following code work with `DEBUG = false` and not `DEBUG = true`

When DEBUG is equal to True the following settings works:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

However when DEBUG is set to false, collect static fails.

My file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your static folder lives in project directory you have to change the setting BASE_DIR according to it ...

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__) + '../../../')
```

Comment: still can't get it to work..is there a way to see a readout of the path it's trying?